# Sonos API Browse container two-line displayy

Tags: sonos

For reason the two-line display of containers in browse are not working, via search it works perfectly. Can someone please review below output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
         <getMetadataResult>
            <index>0</index>
            <count>2</count>
            <total>2</total>
            <mediaCollection>
               <canPlay>true</canPlay>
               <id>album-1200</id>
               <title>En de wind stilde</title>
               <itemType>album</itemType>
               <artistId>artist-5716</artistId>
               <artist>Ds. D.W. Tuinier</artist>
               <albumArtURI>http://***/albumart.php?album_id=1200&amp;size=200</albumArtURI>
            </mediaCollection>
            <mediaCollection>
               <canPlay>true</canPlay>
               <id>album-1163</id>
               <title>De Tas</title>
               <itemType>album</itemType>
               <artistId>artist-5619</artistId>
               <artist>Ben de Raaf</artist>
               <albumArtURI>http://***/albumart.php?album_id=1163&amp;size=200</albumArtURI>
            </mediaCollection>
         </getMetadataResult>
      </getMetadataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Two line display is based on the container type of the parent container.  Alternatively it can also be controlled by using displayTypes (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/423).  Without seeing what the parent type was it is hard to tell exactly what is happening;  what is the request that generates this response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was located in the parent container, the itemType of the parent container should be AlbumList instead of a container.

Many thanks Sonos Developer Advocacy.